# What URLs do I need block annoying social widgets?

Tags: widgets

[Widget Block](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/hgiihiookhijpbhaflohognbhmamdnol?hl=en) is a lovely extension that blocks noisy bloat that is of no use to me and actually makes my browsing experience much worse.

The extension lists the following domains:

```
 facebook.com
 fbcdn.net
 fbshare.me
 twitter.com
 disqus.com
 digg.com
 meebo.com
 publitweet.com
 lijit.com
 chartbeat.com
 causes.com
 postup.com
 conduit.com
 quantserve.com
 google-analytics.com
 gravatar.com
 google.com/buzz
 google.com/cse
 google.com/friendconnect
 stats.wordpress.com
 scorecardresearch.com
 speakertext.com
 snap.com
 snapabug.com
 revsci.net
 badgeville.com
 chomp.com
 wibiya.com
 addthis.com
 woopra.com
 apture.com
 js-kit.com
 yaptor.com
 tweetmeme.com
 getclicky.com
 fmpub.net
 typekit.com
 buysellads.com
 sharethis.com
 outbrain.com
 adtech.us
 mar.gy
 mixpanel.com
 kissmetrics.com
 viglink.com
 fyre.co
 assistly.com
 stumbleupon.com
 delicious.com
 uservoice.com
 linkedin.com
```

Does anyone know a list that I can use to block (most of) these disservices?

*(I have found [these](https://monzta.maltekraus.de/adblock_social.txt) [two](https://fanboy-adblock-list.googlecode.com/hg/fanboy-adblocklist-addon.txt) AdBlock filters, but they use the AdBlock syntax, which makes them useless to me. They might serve you well, though.)*

Comment: What do you mean? Specifically, what's wrong with the blacklist you already have?

Comment: I currently use Ad Muncher on Windows, which blocks malware and ads. I don’t want to bloat my browsers too much with extensions, and I also use many different browsers, so centralizing the blacklisting to something like Ad Muncher would be preferable. However, the syntax of the aforementioned AdBlock filters doesn’t work with Ad Muncher, so I want something more general.

Answer (score 1):

Widget Block seems very difficult to amend the list of domains you want to block.

Why not just install AdBlock and follow the steps in [this tutorial](http://www.techairlines.com/2010/12/12/block-social-buttons-widgets/).

The tutorial explains how to read in a list of domains from a text file.  This is far easier than Widget Block.  The text file used in the tutorial looks be updated every 3 days so there is even less effort required on your part :)

Answer (score 1):

[This extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom) works with the Adblock Plus lists. [Fanboy's list](https://secure.fanboy.co.nz/fanboy-addon.txt) works really well, or use the one you already linked from the Google CDN.

Answer (score 1):

Way back in the dark ages, before FireFox, I started using [SlimBrowser](http://slimbrowser.flashpeak.com/en/). I especially like this browser because it defeats popups by default. Slimbrowser was the first tabbed browser. The popup blocker in the browser automatically kills annoying popup and pop-under ads. It uses internet explorer as it's engine, but because of the intelligence built into the browser, it makes I.E. smarter.